# How to solve DE: $y'''+y''+ y'+ y = 1 + x + e^{x} + \sin{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the particular solution for:

$y'''+y''+ y'+ y = 1 + x + e^{x} + \sin{x}$

It seems as though the only thing I'd need to solve this would be a good substitution, correct? It doesn't seem like Let $y=e^{x}$ works as a substitution.

Comment: You can use the method of undetermined coefficients, or variations of parameters. The first method would be better though, being easier for this specific case. Be careful! If you use undetermined coefficients, you need to find the solution of the homogenous equation first to check if any solution is repeating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is the same method @J.G. gave, I just add explanation of why we take this solution)

First you solve the homogeneous part by setting $y_h=e^{\gamma x}$

Then you have the "scary" equation: $y'''+y''+ y'+ y = 1 + x + e^{x} + \sin{x}$

We can break it to $4$ different equations: $$y_1'''+y_1''+ y_1'+ y_1 = 1 + x\\y_2'''+y_2''+ y_2'+ y_2 = e^x\\y_3'''+y_3''+ y_3'+ y_3 = \sin{x}\\y_p=y_1+y_2+y_3$$(Can you see why?)

Solving $y_i$ shouldn't be a problem using undetermined coefficients method:$$y_1=C_1+C_2x\\y_2=C_3e^x\\y_3=C_4\sin(x)+C_5\cos(x)\\y_p=C_1+C_2x+C_3e^x+C_4\sin(x)+C_5\cos(x)$$When you will work it out you will see that the homogeneous part contains $y_3$ in it, so instead of $y_3$ we will use $x\cdot y_3$ and you will get the the guess of:$$y_p=C_1+C_2x+C_3e^x+C_4x\sin(x)+C_5x\cos(x)$$

Comment: I see. I did not know what "Ansatz" meant so I wasn't sure how to proceed using J.G.'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try the Ansatz $y=a+bx+ce^x+dx\sin x +fx\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$ e^{-x} , \sin x, \cos x$$ as your solutions for the homogeneous equation  $$y'''+y''+ y'+ y = 0$$

For your particular solution  You consider $$A+Bx +C e^{x} + x(D \sin x +E \cos x)$$